# Custom Animation end trigger

Tags: java, android, events, animation

I'm writing a "space invaders" style app and I needed to do the move stop repeat animation that is classic to the game. I got the processes to go one way, using the code below, however when I want to go back, there does not seem to be an easy way to do this. I think the easiest way to do it is to have something happen on the end animation event, however I cannot get the event to trigger, even when calling `super.end();`. I've looked around for a way to trigger the event manually but to no avail. The way I am doing this may be a little sketchy but it works well enough right now to try and make it work all the way.

```
public void start()
{
    if(begin < end) //recursive end condition
    { 
        int distance = interval + begin; //change the distance to be traveled
        //create new animation to do part of the whole animation
        ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(toAnimate, property, begin,distance);
        TimeInterpolator inter = new TimeInterpolator() //makes the animation move with only one frame
        {
            public float getInterpolation(float prog)
            {
                return Math.round(prog * 10) / 10;
            }
        };
        anim.setInterpolator(inter);
        anim.setDuration((long)(500));
        anim.addListener(new AnimatorListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation){}
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
            {
                start(); //start the next part of the movement
            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation){}
            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation){}
        });
        begin = begin + interval; //update end recursion value
        anim.start(); //begin the animation
    }
    super.end(); //this doesn't work... rip
}
```

Comment: why not using TimeAnimator?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void start()
{
    if(begin < end) //recursive end condition
    { 
        int distance = interval + begin; //change the distance to be traveled
        //create new animation to do part of the whole animation
        ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(toAnimate, property, begin,distance);
        TimeInterpolator inter = new TimeInterpolator() //makes the animation move with only one frame
        {
            public float getInterpolation(float prog)
            {
                return Math.round(prog * 10) / 10;
            }
        };
        anim.setInterpolator(inter);
        anim.setDuration((long)(500));
        anim.addListener(new AnimatorListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation){}
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
            {
                begin += interval;
                if(begin < end){
                   start(); //start the next part of the movement
                }
                else{
                    // Do something else
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation){}
            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation){}
        });
        anim.start(); //begin the animation
    }
}
```